# Как исключить все изображения в парсере новостей rss

Tags: php, парсер, img

Ниже рабочий код парсера. Всё работает как надо, но нужно исключить все встречающиеся изображения в самой новости `<description>(.*?)<\/description>` , чтобы остался только текст.
Сама картинка в новости выглядит так:

```
<description> тут новость начинается  
  <center>
     <img style="margin-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 10px" id="*" alt="** " src="/Images/**/**.jpg" align="center" border="0" />
  </center>  
   далее продолжение новости.
</description>
```

Код парсера:

```
function parse_rss_tri($reg_exp_tri, $xml_data_tri) {
preg_match_all($reg_exp_tri, $xml_data_tri, $temp_tri);
return array(
    'count_tri'    => count($temp_tri[0]),
    'title_tri'    => $temp_tri[1],
    'link_tri'     => $temp_tri[2],
    'desc_tri'     => $temp_tri[3],
    'category_tri' => $temp_tri[4],
    'pubDate_tri'  => $temp_tri[5]
);}


function output_rss_tri($pattern_tri, $rss_data_tri) {
for($y=0; $y<$rss_data_tri['count_tri']; $y++) {
    $temp_tri .= sprintf($pattern_tri,
        $rss_data_tri['link_tri'][$y],
        html_entity_decode($rss_data_tri['title_tri'][$y]),
        html_entity_decode($rss_data_tri['category_tri'][$y]),
        html_entity_decode($rss_data_tri['pubDate_tri'][$y]),
        html_entity_decode($rss_data_tri['desc_tri'][$y])
    );
}
return $temp_tri;
}

$url_tri = 'http://link/rss.rss';
$reg_exp_tri  = '#<item>.*?<title>(.*?)<\/title>.*?';
$reg_exp_tri .= '<link>(.*?)<\/link>.*?';
$reg_exp_tri .= '.*?<description>(.*?)<\/description>.*?<category>(.*?)   <\/category>';
$reg_exp_tri .= '.*?<pubDate>(.*?)<\/pubDate>.*?<\/item>#si';

$pattern_tri = '<div><p class="line"><br><span class="post-ident"><a class="post-num" title="перейти к первоисточнику" href=\"%s\">%s</a>
</span><p class="dateclass">%s → %s</p><p>%s</p></p></div>'; 

if ( $xml_data_tri = file_get_contents($url_tri) ) {
$rss_data_tri = parse_rss_tri($reg_exp_tri, $xml_data_tri);

echo output_rss_tri($pattern_tri, $rss_data_tri);
```

}

Comment: Ну это же не код парсера, есть simplexml это парсер, а это я даже парсером не назову. А вообще берёте simplexml получаете description и просто проганяете через `strip_tags()`

Comment: чет я тоже несколько удивлен разбору XML через регулярные выражения.

Comment: По другому не умею :)

Comment: RSS лента это XML документ. Для работы с [XML в пхп](http://php.net/manual/ru/refs.xml.php) есть множество библиотек, наиболее простым будет использование [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.simplexml.php). Можете сразу посмотреть [примеры использования](http://php.net/manual/ru/simplexml.examples-basic.php)